# Who exactly is "them" here?

Tags: meaning

> Obi-Wan: Anakin did not take to his new assignment with much
> enthusiasm.
>
> WINDU: It's very dangerous, putting **them** together. I don't think the
> boy can handle it. I don't trust him.

Who exactly is "them" here? I am pretty sure grammatically, that 'them' could refer to "assignment" and
"enthusiasm".

Source: Star Wars Episode III - Revenge of the Sith (2005)

Comment: Presumably, two people already mentioned (Anakin and a boy?)

Comment: I think in this context Anakin was the boy, the other was presumably Amidala (or maybe Palpatine?). But yes, the "them" refers to the two specific people.

Comment: I hope I may be forgiven for having _absolutely no knowledge whatsoever_ of Star Wars or its characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question requires context to answer it. The assignment that Anakin has been given was to spy on Supreme Chancellor Palpatine. Mace Windu is thus saying that putting them — Anakin and Palpatine — together is dangerous. Indeed subsequent events bear this out.